# Express.js with Passenger and Apache "Application could not be started"

Tags: node.js, apache, express, passenger

I am trying to deploy an Express REST API (generated with express-generator) with Passenger with the Apache integration mode but it doesn't work. I think the problem comes from the configuration file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's code directory is
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myAppName/code/public
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/myAppName/code

    # Tell Passenger that your app is a Node.js app
    PassengerAppType node
    PassengerStartupFile bin/www

    # Relax Apache security settings
    <Directory /var/www/myAppName/code/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
      #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I did as explained in the PhusionPassenger documentation except I just set PassengerStartupFile to bin/www because it's an Express app but it seems that i'ts not enough it still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Merha. Please be more specific. We can't help you if the only indication we have is: "it doesn't work"...